# Set pagefile to be automaticly manged by windows in group policy

Tags: active-directory, pagefile

We have a 2003 domain, and i need to set the page file to managed by the system ( For some reason it has a manual size set ). I was wondering where i find the group policy in active directory to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us why you believe a manually set size is a bad thing.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx

In short its rare that you the user know better then windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be posible, but can be done via reg setting that you again can push out.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"PagingFiles"=hex(7):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,66,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,20,00,30,00,20,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
```